# Using CKeditor in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textarea, ckeditor

I want to use my configured ckeditor in my ror application,

I have downloaded my ckeditor from

```
http://ckeditor.com/download (.tar.gz)
```

, and then configured it by editing ckeditor.pack (adding only those plugin which I need)
then compiled it using the command:

```
java -jar ckpackager.jar ckeditor.pack
```

Then I checked running my ckeditor and it works perfectly fine.

then as given in this post:

```
http://ferric.net/articles/2009/09/07/ckeditor-3-0-and-rails/
```

I copied my ckeditor directory to RAILS_ROOT/public/javascripts and edited my RAILS_ROOT/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file to :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reader</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     if ($('textarea').length > 0)
     {       
       var data = $('textarea');
       $.each(data, function(i)
       {
         CKEDITOR.replace(data[i].id);
       }
       );     
     }  
  }); 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I tried to run my view, which is :

```
<h2> Write your article</h2>
<p>
<textarea  >Test Text</textarea>
</p>
```

I get a simple textarea, not ckeditor.

When I tried to find out the reason it said:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What is it , that I am doing wrong, and how can I use my ckeditor in ROR ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked out this problem by copying my ckeditor to RAILS_ROOT/public/javascripts/ and then editing my views/layouts/application.html.erb to add this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
```

in head finally making it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reader</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

And it worked using

```
 <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" name="editor1" >Test Text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Rails 3.1, you will have to put your assets into the "app->assets" folder. Rails 3.1 introduced a new concept called the "asset pipeline" which basically grabs all of your assets and combines/optimizes them. You can read up on it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

But you dont have to install it by hand, you can just use this gem:  https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: I am installing it by hand because I have configured it as per my use , I kept my ckeditor directory in assest folder, but still I get 404 . any help?